# C++ substructures

Tags: c++, c, structure

Hey I'd like to get some help with substructures.
I have exercise with following instructions:
There's a 1 library

In that library there are 10 authors (book writers)

Each of book writers can have 15 books max.

I must use 2 functions:
                      - to read all the informations
                      - to sort books from A to Z

I wrote structures now I get lost how to read them because of substructures

Code's here: http://pastebin.com/gMaZXR89

That's how far I got, I get stuck at those "gets".
I would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: \why are you using `gets` and not `cin`?

Comment: Also why not paste code that a) compiles and b)as a hope in hell of doing something?

Comment: Well that's how we do it if there's a char in this case

Comment: Have you already managed to read authors alone? If yes, have you managed reading authors together with their books?

Comment: @PeterG. - Perhaps that is the problem not being able to read a book

Comment: I tried (not on my place), here I just wrote how I do it and it's not working

Comment: @user3673312 - what do you think `int main() { return 0; }` does?

Comment: Man I know i must call functions there but I just gave example how I did in school with those readings..

Comment: @user3673312 - Get it to compile. Get it to call the function. Decide if you are using C or C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your problem I suppose....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Book
{
    char title[30];//unneceserly use Author author[30] because you refer at the book by its author
    float price;
    int year_of_publication;
};

struct Author
{
    char name[30],subname[30];
    int birth_date;
    Book x[14];//a max of 15 books/author
};

struct Library
{
    /*there are 10 book writers*/Author y[9];//because you defined struct Author now you can use it without struct.
};

void readBooks(struct Library lib/*there is a single library*/, const int n=10)//there are 10 book writers
{
    int i,j,how_many;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Input "<<i+1<<". authors name"<<endl;
        gets(lib.y[i].name);//you call the array y not the type Author...
        cout<<"Input "<<i+1<<". authors subname"<<endl;
        gets(lib.y[i].subname);
        cout<<"How many books author"<<i+1<<" write?";
        cin>>how_many;

        for(j=0;j<how_many;++j)
           {
              cout<<"Input "<<i+1<<". authors "<<j+1<<" book title "<<endl;
              gets(lib.y[i].x[j].title);
              cout<<"Input "<<i+1<<". authors "<<j+1<<" book price "<<endl;
              cin>>lib.y[i].x[j].price;
              cout<<"Input "<<i+1<<". authors "<<j+1<<" book year of publication "<<endl;
              cin>>lib.y[i].x[j].year_of_publication;
           }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Library l;//can`t write struct in front because it is defined up...
    readBooks(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the in the lines

```
gets(tab[i].Author[y].name);
gets(tab[i].Author[y].subname);
```

Author is not the name of the array of structs of type Author that you defines in the Library struct, it's name is y.

So it should be something like this:

```
   gets(tab[i].y[j].name);
   gets(tab[i].y[j].subname);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Click the checkmark near the answer. 
This let's other users reading your question know that this is a solution that worked.